# VBA protected cells but still allowing edits

Tags: excel, vba

I have a python script that edits contents of a certain column and VBA that checks to see if this column has changed. When it detects a change, it locks the column from user edits. It is successful in protecting the worksheet but the cells can still be edited. I can't understand why this is happening.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Protect As String
Dim NotProtectRange As String
ProtectRange = "A1:A1049576"
NotProtectRange = "B1:XFD1048576"

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range(ProtectRange)) Is Nothing Then
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect
  Range(NotProtectRange).Locked = False
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, Contents:=True

End If

End Sub
```

I expect that when I double click the cells in the range `ProtectRange`, I should not be able to edit them. But instead, I can edit them. So how do I fix this?

Comment: If the cells are not locked then protecting the sheet does not prevent editing. Are the cells in `ProtectRange` locked?

Comment: FYI in a worksheet code module you can use (eg) `Me.Unprotect` in place of (eg) `Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for clarifying that. I used Range(ProtectRange).Locked = True and it solved the issue. I was initially under the impression that protecting the worksheet would lock all cells excluding cells in NotProtectRange.

Comment: The default state for a cell's `Locked` property is `True`, so you may have set it to False at some previous point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cells are not locked then protecting the sheet does not prevent editing.

```
Me.Range(ProtectRange).Locked = True
```

should resolve the problem.